# Why is the link in bootstrap button component not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have these two links, where the first one is not working and i need to use it to send the items, but the second one with a normal href is, why would this happen?

```
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
<Button
        as={Link}
        to={{ pathname: "/MyStoreCheckout", items: cart && cart.items }}
        variant="primary"
      >
        Pay
      </Button>
      <a
        href="/MyStoreCheckout"
      >
        Pay
      </a>
```

Comment: You can try this `<Button tag={Link} to="/somewhere" />`

Comment: EVEN that doesnt work it was my first try @SifatHaque